# gtk_init caused crash on ubuntu 16.04 if program run without sudo

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, gtk

gtk_init caused crash on ubuntu 16.04 if run program without sudo. If run with sudo, then have not problem. On other ubuntu versions also have not problem with and without sudo.

Minimally reproducible example:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        printf("%d\n", i);
        usleep(1000 * 1000);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
Thread 2 "dconf worker" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0xb6567b40 (LWP 6735)]
0xb71bbfd0 in g_source_set_ready_time () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
(gdb) bt
#0  0xb71bbfd0 in g_source_set_ready_time () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#1  0xb73e8bf4 in g_task_get_type () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0
#2  0xb744b6a0 in ?? () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0
#3  0xb743eb00 in ?? () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0
#4  0xb73bd0e9 in g_initable_init () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0
#5  0xb743f230 in g_bus_get_sync () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0
#6  0xb668c314 in ?? () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libdconfsettings.so
#7  0xb668c423 in ?? () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libdconfsettings.so
#8  0x0807e22a in g_main_context_dispatch ()
#9  0x0807e638 in g_main_context_iterate.isra ()
#10 0x0807e700 in g_main_context_iteration ()
#11 0xb668c58b in ?? () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libdconfsettings.so
#12 0x0809eabd in g_thread_proxy ()
#13 0xb7aaf295 in start_thread (arg=0xb6567b40) at pthread_create.c:333
#14 0xb79d10ae in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/i386/clone.S:114
```

I tried to compare strace output with sudo and without - without sudo is being created problem thread `dconf worker`, but if run with sudo it thread is not being created and programm work correctly

What can be done to fix this problem?

---

UPD: Stacktrace with `libglib2.0-0-dbg

```
Thread 2 "dconf worker" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0xb6567b40 (LWP 3574)]
0xb71bbfd0 in g_source_set_ready_time (source=0xb5c09938, ready_time=-1)
    at /build/glib2.0-2aRhhS/glib2.0-2.48.2/./glib/gmain.c:1786
1786    /build/glib2.0-2aRhhS/glib2.0-2.48.2/./glib/gmain.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  0xb71bbfd0 in g_source_set_ready_time (source=0xb5c09938, ready_time=-1)
    at /build/glib2.0-2aRhhS/glib2.0-2.48.2/./glib/gmain.c:1786
#1  0xb73e8bf4 in g_task_get_type () at /build/glib2.0-2aRhhS/glib2.0-2.48.2/./gio/gtask.c:1907
#2  0xb73e8bf4 in g_task_get_type () at /build/glib2.0-2aRhhS/glib2.0-2.48.2/./gio/gtask.c:590
#3  0xb744b6a0 in _g_dbus_worker_new () at /build/glib2.0-2aRhhS/glib2.0-2.48.2/./gio/gdbusprivate.c:227
#4  0xb744b6a0 in _g_dbus_worker_new () at /build/glib2.0-2aRhhS/glib2.0-2.48.2/./gio/gdbusprivate.c:267
#5  0xb744b6a0 in _g_dbus_worker_new (stream=0xb5c016c8, capabilities=G_DBUS_CAPABILITY_FLAGS_UNIX_FD_PASSING, initially_frozen=0, message_received_callback=0xb7438400 <on_worker_message_received>, message_about_to_be_sent_callback=0xb7435eb0 <on_worker_message_about_to_be_sent>, disconnected_callback=0xb74359c0 <on_worker_closed>, user_data=0xb5c04818)
    at /build/glib2.0-2aRhhS/glib2.0-2.48.2/./gio/gdbusprivate.c:1649
#6  0xb743eb00 in initable_init (initable=0xb5c04818, cancellable=0x0, error=0xb6567068)
    at /build/glib2.0-2aRhhS/glib2.0-2.48.2/./gio/gdbusconnection.c:2573
#7  0xb73bd0e9 in g_initable_init (initable=0xb5c04818, cancellable=0x0, error=0xb6567068)
    at /build/glib2.0-2aRhhS/glib2.0-2.48.2/./gio/ginitable.c:112
#8  0xb743f230 in g_bus_get_sync (bus_type=G_BUS_TYPE_SESSION, cancellable=0x0, error=0xb6567068)
    at /build/glib2.0-2aRhhS/glib2.0-2.48.2/./gio/gdbusconnection.c:7254
#9  0xb668c314 in  () at /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libdconfsettings.so
#10 0xb668c423 in  () at /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libdconfsettings.so
#11 0x0807e22a in g_main_context_dispatch ()
#12 0x0807e638 in g_main_context_iterate.isra ()
#13 0x0807e700 in g_main_context_iteration ()
#14 0xb668c58b in  () at /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libdconfsettings.so
#15 0x0809eabd in g_thread_proxy ()
#16 0xb7aaf295 in start_thread (arg=0xb6567b40) at pthread_create.c:333
#17 0xb79d10ae in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/i386/clone.S:114
```

Comment: With [google "thread dconf worker"](https://www.google.com/search?q=thread+dconf+worker), I found this as first hit: [ubuntu forums: Thread: applications crash on terminal](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2185226). It might be worth a look as well as other google hits. (Asking in ubuntu forum would've been my second hint.) ;-)

Comment: Unfortunately, in google I did not find anything suitable for me. The forum found a link to the ubuntu, but this was not my case. Thanks for the advice, I'll try to ask also there

Comment: Hi! Could you install the libglib2.0-0-dbg package and take the stacktrace again? That could be really helpful

Comment: Added stacktrace with libglib2.0-0-dbg

Comment: What happens if you run your program with the two environment variables `MALLOC_CHECK_=2` and `G_SLICE=always-malloc` together? Check if you get any warning message in the terminal and if the stacktrace is different

Comment: I tried. There are no messages in terminal, stacktrace is no different

Comment: As a last try, add `g_type_ensure (G_TYPE_DBUS_CONNECTION);` `g_type_ensure (G_TYPE_TASK);` `g_type_ensure (G_TYPE_MEMORY_INPUT_STREAM);` before `gtk_init();`. Probably only the first is needed. See here: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/glib/issues/541

Comment: `error: 'g_type_ensure' was not declared in this scope`, `error: 'G_TYPE_TASK' was not declared in this scope`. 
What should i include?

Comment: I include `#include <glib-object.h>` but still get errors

Comment: Including `<gtk/gtk.h>` should suffice. At least, works here

Comment: Headers in my toolchain from version 2.26, `g_type_ensure` appeared in 2.34

Comment: With `unset GTK2_MODULES unset GTK_MODULES unset GTK_IM_MODULE` before run program, program was not crashed. But I do not fully understand why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unset `GTK2_MODULES`, `GTK_MODULES` and `GTK_IM_MODULE` fixed this problem, but i don't understend why it work

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    unsetenv("GTK2_MODULES");
    unsetenv("GTK_MODULES");
    unsetenv("GTK_IM_MODULE");

    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        printf("%d\n", i);
        usleep(1000 * 1000);
    }
    return 0;
}
```